# Delete a row by pressing the button

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

what I wanted to do was that a button would appear in the last cell of the DataTable row and when the user clicked that same row would have to be removed. I couldn't find anything that could help me.

```
import 'package:app/views/login_page.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListPageState createState() => _ListPageState();
}

Future<List> getBookings() async {
  var ref =
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("server/bookings/" + currentCard + "/");
  DataSnapshot event = await ref.get();

  List<DataRow> bookings = [];
  for (var meal in event.children) {
    bookings.add(
      DataRow(
        cells: [
          DataCell(Text(meal.child("data").value.toString())),
          DataCell(Text(meal.child("tipo").value.toString())),
          DataCell(Text(meal.child("local").value.toString())),
          DataCell(IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
            onPressed: () {
              //Delete row
            },
          )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  print(bookings);
  return bookings;
}

class _ListPageState extends State<ListPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        Center(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: getBookings(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return DataTable(
                  showCheckboxColumn: true,
                  columns: const [
                    DataColumn(label: Text("Data")),
                    DataColumn(label: Text("Tipo")),
                    DataColumn(label: Text("Local")),
                    DataColumn(label: Text("")),
                  ],
                  rows: snapshot.data as List<DataRow>);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The biggest difficulty for me is to get the index of the clicked line to be able to delete it

Comment: If you are trying to remove the last element of a list then there's a method list.removeLast(); which does just that. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with your approach is accessing and changing the data you get with your future.

This code shows the problem in an minimal example:

```
class ExampleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  ExampleWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ExampleWidget> createState() => _ExampleWidgetState();

  Future<List<Text>> getData() async {
    return [Text('1'), Text('2')];
  }
}

class _ExampleWidgetState extends State<ExampleWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Text>>(
        future: widget.getData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return Container();
          return Column(children: snapshot.data!);
        });
  }
}
```

As you can see there is no way to edit the list afterwards. To make it accessible, it needs to be added to a state of a widget. The simplest approach here would be just to save your response as a field in your state and build the widgets in the "build" method of your state. Here an example:

```
class ExampleWidget2 extends StatefulWidget {
  ExampleWidget2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ExampleWidget2> createState() => _ExampleWidgetState2();
}

class _ExampleWidgetState2 extends State<ExampleWidget2> {
  List<String>? _data;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  Future getData() async {
    _data = ['1', '2'];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_data == null) {
      return Container();
    } else {
      List<Widget> widgets = [];

      for (String item in _data!) {
        widgets.add(ElevatedButton(
             onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _data!.remove(item);
              });
            },
            child: Text(item)));
      }

      return Column(children: widgets);
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I added buttons in the second example that remove rows on click by manipulating the state variable and setting the state.